# What is the Japanese font used in the ending credit of Steins;Gate anime?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

This frame is taken from the ending credit of *Steins;Gate* anime.

[image]

What is the Japanese font used?

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please take a look around [tour] to learn who and what we are as a community. Please also read through [ask] and [answer] to understand how best to frame a query, and what to expect of answers. You should also look at this canonical question on Font Identification, and then consider revising your question based on the information you'll find there:
https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [anime_font's tweet](https://twitter.com/anime_font/status/947089100305076225), the font used in the ending credit of *STEINS;GATE* anime is [**グレコ M** by Fontworks Inc.](https://fontworks.co.jp/fontsearch/item?GrecoStd-M&word=%E5%B2%A1%E9%83%A8%E5%80%AB%E5%A4%AA%E9%83%8E).

> [image: グレコ M demonstration]